# Comments posted to profile from Facebook Comments Plugin cannot be liked or commented

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I just added Comments Plugin to my website using [Facebook for WordPress](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/wordpress/) (A WordPress plugin). And I my friend tested commenting on the web page with option "Post to Profile" checked.

The post appeared on my friend's profile but when I tried to like or comment on the post, it says

> "Unable to like this object because it is not accessible (it may have been removed or you may no longer have permission to see it)."

Does anybody know how to fix this?

This is the web page url http://www.baagames.com/2013/10/simcity-cities-of-tomorrow-gameplay
And this is my friend's post http://on.fb.me/H1eydT

Answer (score 1):

This has been ongoing since the last 2 weeks. Every WordPress with Facebook Comments installed  has the same issue. Asked the WP. Nothing. Asked FB. Nothing. The FB comment developers say it is FB causing the problem and to wait. That's all I know. VERY FRUSTRATING AND STRANGE!